# execute enc command from QtProgram

Tags: c++, qt, encryption, openssl

I have the following question, I want to encrypt a file with openssl, but it doesn't give me any result, I get the message that it was encrypted, but in the Qt output panel, I get an invalid command.
Any suggestion of how I could do it would be appreciated, I am using QProcess and Openssl 1.1 for it, below I leave the code, thanks in advance.

code:

```
   #include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QProcess>
#include <QMessageBox>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
  : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
  delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  QProcess *proc=new QProcess(this);
  QStringList argv;
  argv.append(" enc -des-cbc -a -in C:/Users/Lincoln/Desktop/test.txt -pass pass:123");
  argv.append(" -out C:/Users/Lincoln/Desktop/test.enc");
  bool res=proc->startDetached("D:/OpenSSL-Win64/bin/openssl.exe",argv);
  if(res)
    QMessageBox::information(this,qApp->applicationName(),"Archivo encriptado");
  else
    QMessageBox::critical(this,qApp->applicationName(),"Hubo un error");
}
```

[image]

Note that I get an encrypted file, but below it says something else.

Comment: Why do your `argv` strings have a leading space?

Comment: Also, startDetached just starts the process, it doesn't wait for the program to complete.

Comment: You should put each piece of the command line separately into `argv`, as in `argv.append("enc"); argv.append("-des-cbc");` and so on. As written, `openssl.exe` receives the whole string `enc -des-cbc ...` as the first argument, and that string of course doesn't match any valid command.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the problem.

```
argv.append(" enc -des-cbc -a -in C:/Users/Lincoln/Desktop/test.txt -pass pass:123");
```

probably needs to be:

```
argv.append("enc");
argv.append("-des-cbc");
argv.append("-a");
argv.append("-in");
argv.append("C:/Users/Lincoln/Desktop/test.txt");
argv.append("-pass");
argv.append("pass:123");
```

Do the same for the `-out` set of parameters